# Probability density function for a random variable with discontinuous cumulative function

Tags: calculus, probability

I fail to see how to use delta functions in order to find the density function for, say a random variable $X$, with the following cumulative function:

$$F_X(s)=\begin{cases}
0 & s\leq0\\
s^{4} & 0<s<\frac{1}{2}\\
s & \frac{1}{2}\leq s\leq1\\
1 & 1<s
\end{cases}$$

I thought about summing the derivatives in each segment with the delta function centered where each segment starts, but that doesn't seems to be close to work. What is the right way to tackle this kind of problems?

Comment: It is not really common to use the word density here as the distribution function is not even continuous. If you want to take the atom at $\frac12$ into account, as it has weight $\frac12-\frac1{2^4}=\frac7{16}$, you can write $\frac7{16}\delta_{\frac12}$.

Comment: $F$ jumps from $1/16$ to $1/2,$ a jump of size $1/2-1/16=7/16$ at $s=1/2.$ So $\frac 7 {16}\delta\left(s-\frac 1 2 \right)$ is part of the derivative of $F. \qquad$

Comment: Every distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed in an absolutely continuous plus continuous plus discontinuous part. Your example has an absolutely continuous part and a pair of jumps.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Did you miss the word singular somewhere?